# XSL How to find the greater of 2 strings?

Tags: xslt

Have the below newbie question on how to compare and find the greater of 2 strings please -

```
<xsl:variable name="String1" select="ABC"/>
<xsl:variable name="String2" select="DEF"/>
```

My focus of comparison between the 2 strings is based on the first letter being greater than the other, so, i did this -

```
<xsl:variable name="String1First" select="substring($String1,1,1)"/>
<xsl:variable name="String2First" select="substring($String2,1,1)"/>
```

so i have the values of the first letters in string1First & String2First for the compare.

Now the actual comparison is the issue - just tried to check if string1 > string2 but that didnt give me the right result obviously.

```
<xsl:variable name="Output">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="'$String1First' &gt; '$String2First'">
            <xsl:text> First string is greater </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> Second string is greater </xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

tried using compare function, but that didn't seem to work.

```
<xsl:variable name="Output">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(compare('$String1First', '$String2First')) = 1">
            <xsl:text> First string is greater </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> Second string is greater </xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

also tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="Alphabet" select="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
<xsl:number name="PosNo" select="index-of-string($Alphabet,$String1First)">
<xsl:number name="PosNo2" select="index-of-string($Alphabet,$String2First)">
```

to compare as numbers by taking the position, but got the whole format wrong.

Could you please help with the easiest way to achieve this please?

Many thanks for your kind assistance.

Comment: `<xsl:variable name=String1 select="ABC"/>` is not even syntactically correct so it is hard to tell how the rest of your post should make any sense. If you use `<xsl:variable name="String1" select="'ABC'"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="String2" select="'DEF'"/>`  then I am sure you can use the XPath 2.0 `compare($String1, $String2)` and check the numeric result (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-compare) as needed. You can even use `$String1 gt $String2`, if you check https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#mapping you will see that `gt defined as `numeric-greater-than(fn:compare(A, B), 0)`

Comment: You need to say whether this is XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Facilities in XSLT 1.0 for comparing strings are very limited indeed: basically the only way is to create a node-set and sort it, and even that needs extensions. By contrast, XSLT 2.0 offers any number of ways of doing it, depending on your requirements (e.g. collations).

Comment: corrected. Its xslt 1.0. 'gt' operator seems to work for numbers only and not for strings. it doesn't recognize compare.

Comment: So what does `<xsl:variable name="String1" select="ABC"/>` do in your opinion? That selects the child element(s) named `ABC`, it is not a string. And `'$String1First'` does not reference any variable if that is what you want, instead it is a string literal starting with a dollar sign. As for the `gt` operator, it does not exist in XPath 1.0. The `>` operators exists but does indeed only do number comparison. No idea however why you say you can use `compare` as that is XPath 2.0 also. And where do you find `index-of-string`?